Is this Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE) scenario possible?
I'm a stats novice, and I'm currently looking into ML estimates for phylogenetic trees. I've had this "philosophical" problem with the MLE method in general ever since I learned about it. Essentially, consider the scenario in which you have this type of likelihood function $L(\theta)$:

Since the MLE method will choose the $\theta$ that maximizes $L(\theta)$ (i.e., the point that does that), a point on the right blob will be chosen. However, based on this probability distribution, it seems pretty clear that a $\theta$ in the left blob is more reflective of the actual PDF, it just so happens that the smaller blob on the right has a bigger peak. I've looked into problems with the MLE, and I see things like susceptible to outliers, but I am not sure if the scenario I've presented here falls into any of them. Can anyone explain to me if this is an actual shortcoming of the MLE?
EDIT: Thank you for the answers. I realized that I perhaps should've been more precise in my initial question. Let $\theta_l$ be the argument locally maximizing  on the left blob, and let $\theta_r$ be the argument locally maximizing  on the right blob (i.e., the global maximum). Now, even though it is true that $\theta_r$ does give us an underlying distribution that has a higher probability of generating the data than $\theta_l$, $\theta_l$ might be more reflective of the actual underlying distribution as the $\theta_r$ peak could just be a chance anomaly. E.g., note that the right blob can have an arbitrarily small area and still be taller than the left blob, meaning that even though the range $[\theta_l - \epsilon, \theta_l + \epsilon]$ for a small $\epsilon > 0$ captures a higher ratio of the underlying distributions than $[\theta_r - \epsilon, \theta_r + \epsilon]$, we will still end up choosing $\theta_r$. Thus, I can imagine a scenario in which our actual parameter for the underlying distribution is $\theta_l$, but some outlier or such led the parameter $\theta_r$ to have an abnormally high peak although the parameter is not reflective at all of the actual underlying distribution.
TLDR: Is the fact that we choose the maximizing point an issue and wouldn't choosing
$$\tilde{\theta} = \text{argmax}_{\theta \in \mathbf{R}} \int_{\theta-\epsilon}^{\theta + \epsilon} L(x) dx$$
for some $\epsilon > 0$ make the MLE estimate better?

Hi: I'm not sure if this is what you are getting at with your example but the MLE can have problems from a "robustness" point of view. By this, it is meant that one odd-oultying observation can have serious effects on the  MLE. On the other hand, the median, which is another estimator ( and it's usually not the MLE ), is much more robust to outliers ( but possibly biased. MLE is consistent so unbiased asymptotically ). You should google for things like "influence function" or "robustness" if you're interested in this concept.

Hi: I re-read your question and since you mentioned that you are pretty new to stats, forget the influence function. "Robustness" is a good thing to google for and intro-textbooks will discuss it also.

@marko Can you explain what you mean by "it seems pretty clear that a $\theta$
in the left blob is more reflective of the actual PDF..."? It sounds like you are conflating the shape of the likelihood function with the shape of the underlying probability distribution of the random variable generating the data. They are completely different quantities.

Thank you for your answers. I realized I should've been more precise, so I edited the question. Should make more sense now.

@statsplease i think this is exactly what is confusing OP. Maybe post this as an answer ?

The reason to use the MLE is because in the limit of infinite data it will be efficient and unbiased. For reasonably small sample sizes it will often be close to efficient and unbiased as well, and the example from your image is an untypical case.

If you observe a Likelihood function like that, it could also mean the model is misspecified. Without knowing more about the problem, it's hard to say, but imagine fitting a Gaussian mixture with a single Gaussian for example

After reading the edit I think your question boils down to a concern about the uncertainty of the MLE estimate. Your right peak is narrower and you seem concerned that deviations in the data would lead to rapid drops in the maximized likelihood as we move away from the original estimate. You can perform a bootstrap of the MLE estimate to gauge the uncertainty.

The value of $\theta$ which gives the maximum in the likelihood (the peak in the right of your graph) is the state of nature with optimal capability to generate your data. The wide peak to the left shows that there are many competitors nearly as good, but that is no reason to choose any of them.
Think in terms of choosing a person for a post. You have one candidate with best credentials, quite different from the others; then, a bunch of candidates all alike, nearly as good. Would you choose one of this group, on the ground that they are more numerous?

Regarding your edit: a) Your proposal of $\tilde\theta$ makes it dependent on $\epsilon$; you would then have to choose a value for $\epsilon$. b) Your proposal is akin to saying: "In a personnel selection problem, choose not the optimal candidate, but a candidate which is close to a large pool of like candidates. c) In small samples, it is true that the MLE can be dependent on outliers and give odd behaviour, it relies on large samples for its optimality properties.

The example with choosing candidates is not so good. The candidate with the best credentials sounds nice, but it has a much larger probability to be wrong by a large margin in comparison to the candidates with slightly lower credentials. You equate the highest likelihood to 'the best credentials', and continue the example from there, but this  comparison is not well motivated.
